# How to synchronize entire thunderbird profile with Ubuntu-One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird, sync

Is it possible to synchronize the entire Thunderbird profile folder with Ubuntu-One (or Sparkleshare)? Or will I have some serious problems doing that.
Is there anybody out there having experiences with this?

Comment: It would be great if we could sync some things and not all. Mail for instance can already be IMAP, extensions can be downloaded again on the target machine. Syncing custom settings, signatures, etc. is more important and less space consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used Ubuntu One (I use Dropbox), but this should be possible: Open the file manager (Nautilus), enable viewing hidden files and folders, right click on the `.thunderbird` folder in your home directory, and enable syncing to Ubuntu One.

If you are using Thunderbird on two (or more) machines and sync both the profiles to Ubuntu One, there could be problems with both machines performing conflicting writes on the profile. But as long as it's synced from only one machine, it should be fine. Do keep in mind the storage space limit on Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to sync Thunderbird in Ubuntu using Dropbox cloud service, you can simply move your profile folder from location "~/.thunderbird/profileID.profile/" into Dropbox folder and change following two lines in "~/.thunderbird/profiles.ini" file as follows:

IsRelative=0

Path=~/Dropbox/profileID.default

I have found it in following thread:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder_-_Thunderbird

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried by myself but it seems to me that it's possible.

1. Make a copy of your existing profile. It should be stored in this folder :
   Home/.thunderbird/something.default
2. Paste this in your UbuntuOne or Sparkleshare folder
3. Run thunderbird's profile manager : enter "thunderbird --profilemanager" in a Terminal window
4. Create Profile > Next > Choose folder > Choose the folder you just pasted in your cloud folder.
5. Try Thunderbird with the new profile. If it runs well than return to the profile  manager and delete the old one.

To me the biggest issues with having your profile stored in the cloud are :
- sync issues when cloud sync is down (unfortunately it happens sometime !)
- space issues if you have a huge amount of mails

Have a nice day